# why explicit narrowing a variable is not giving error in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a variable `a` whose type is `Int` and when I convert it to `Byte` It is simply circling with the `min` and `max` value of the respective type

```
fun main(){
   var a : Int = -130
   println("hello kotlin ${a.toByte()}")
}

output :-
hello kotlin 126
```

This will give a wrong value.So, Why kotlin is not giving error on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documented](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/to-byte.html) behavior of `Int.toByte` is:

```
The resulting Byte value is represented by the least significant 8 bits of this Int value.
```

which is `126` (hex value `7E`) for an `Int` value of `-130` (hex value `FFFFFF7E`).

Comment: Where is that doc ?

Comment: I added a link to my answer (click on "documented")

Comment: @VikasAcharya Note this is consistent with Java: `byte b = (byte) -130` will give you `b == 126`. In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if that's pretty much the code (i.e. the cast) used when running on the JVM.